# How can I upgrade a BIRT 2.5 report to BIRT 4.2

Tags: java, report, upgrade, birt

I have an error with BIRT. I want to run a Report, which works fine in BIRT 2.5, in BIRT 4.2, but it gives the error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Not supported function (Element ID:250)
```

Also, how can I upgrade/convert an old report to BIRT 4.2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, all ealier BIRT reports will work on later platforms. There may be some minor error in the orginal 2.5 report that was not an issue, but now causes an error in 4.2.  If you switch from 'Layout' view to 'XML Source' view you can search for the ID '250' to narrow down which element is causing the issue, and correct it.